# Godot Firebase "Logout" method?

Tags: firebase, godot

So I am using Godot and firebase with RestAPI part, however I don't see a method or information on a way to "Logout" someone that has logged in with there credentials, after they log in, do whatever in the game, then "LOGOUT", if possible to clear there credentials, cache, or whatever.. I do have them going back to the main menu in the log in screen and clear the text boxes... but not sure if possible to make sure to clear it completely... is that possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: Being a RestAPI, it is supposed to not hold state, such as being logged in or not. So it makes sense that there is no log out. For what I understand, the API gives you login tokens that you are supposed to send back on further requests. These tokens expire, by the way. Logging out would be erasing any copy of the tokens you had from the system.

Comment: I gotya, so further dumb question then, Would i then make it look as though its logging out, example switching back to the main log in page and clear the text since its giving login tokens? because I do want to send some data to the RESTAPI to store into a database of the user or player's info stats so when they log back in... it will restore there stats from when they logged out.

Comment: If you are doing email and password authentication, you can keep the email, so the user does not have to type it again every time. However, if you are asking for password, don't keep the password at all. Either the login attempt failed, thus the password is wrong, and you erase it and have the user type it again… Or the password is correct, you got a token, so you don't need the password… And since you would ask for it again on log out (or if the token expired), so erase it too. Well, to be fair, you could have a "remember password" feature, but erasing it should be the default.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finally find a solution, looking at the godot firebase RestAPI, and calling https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth, this is good.